# Cursor object required in Python sqlite3 database wrapper?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, contextmanager

In this sqlite3 database wrapper class, is using a sqlite3.Cursor object necessary/best practice?

I wrote a wrapper around an sqlite3 database as a context manager. Typically, the sqlite3.Cursor object is required to make fetch calls after executing sql statements (unless everything is run in a `with conn:` context manager), but in my wrapper it doesn't seem to be a problem calling .execute(...).fetchone() on the conn object directly without a Cursor object or `with self.conn:` statements. Why is this? Is this best practice?

```
class TweetedDB():

    def __init__(self, db_filename='tweeted.db'):
        self.db_filename = db_filename


    def __enter__(self):
        self._connect()
        self._create_table()
        return self


    def __exit__(self, exception_type, exception_value, traceback):
        if self.conn:
            self.conn.commit()
            self.conn.close()


    def _connect(self):
        try:
            self.conn = sqlite3.connect(self.db_filename)
        except sqlite3.Error:
            logging.exception('Failed to connect to database!')


    def _create_table(self, name='paintings'):
        paintings_sql = '''
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {} (
                id integer PRIMARY KEY,
                url text NOT NULL UNIQUE,
                artist text,
                title text,
                year text)
            '''.format(name)

        self.conn.execute(paintings_sql)

    # Skipping some methods here...

    def is_duplicate(self, url):
        ''' Check if `url` already exists in database. '''
        dupl_check_sql = '''
            SELECT url FROM paintings WHERE url=?
        '''
        return self.conn.execute(dupl_check_sql, (url,)).fetchone()
```

I expected an error because I was calling method() and fetchone() on connect object directly, but everything runs okay... what's going on?

Comment: All I've ever seen in the docs was that this is a "non-standard" way of running queries and never any actual ramifications

Comment: *"I expected an error"*: I'm sure, you have done `with <object ref>:` before `<object ref>.is_duplicate(...` because you don't **invalidate** `self.conn` in `def __exit__`, therefore `self.conn` still exists.